# How get data from database in Go&Beego?

Tags: mysql, go, beego

I try create a simple REST service on Go&Beego.

I can not understand the logic of Beego.

All examples have information on how to retrieve just one item while I need to get all items.

In case of API.

**Controller:**

```
package controllers
import (
    "api/models"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type UserController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (u *UserController) GetAll() {
    users := models.GetAllUsers()
    u.Data["json"] = users
    u.ServeJSON()
}
```

**Model:**

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
)

var (
    UserList map[int]*User
)

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(User))

    UserList = make(map[int]*User)

    u := User{1, "Chandler", "Bing", "chandlerbing@gmail.com"}
    UserList[1] = &u
}

type User struct {
    Id int `form:"id"`
    First_name string `form:"first_name"`
    Last_name string `form:"last_name"`
    Email string `form:"email"`
}

func GetAllUsers() map[int]*User {
    return UserList
}
```

That works! But, how can I get data from database?

Database connections are ok (MySQL)

Comment: Execute sql query, process results, return'em?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QueryTable` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/beego/beedoc/blob/master/en-US/mvc/model/query.md#all)

```
var users []*User
num, err := o.QueryTable("user").Filter("name", "slene").All(&users)
```

In your case your `GetAllUsers` should look like this but I didn't tested it.

```
func GetAllUsers() map[int]*User {
    usrs, err := orm.QueryTable("users").Values(&UserList)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return UserList
}
```